# excess @ in printing array elements in c

Tags: c

I've written a c program to recursively reverse a 10 char array:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void rev(char *, char *);
int a = 0;
void main()
{
    char in[10], out[10];
    scanf("%s", in);
    rev(in, out);
    printf("in  is:%s\n", in);
    printf("out is:%s\n", out);
    for(a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        printf("out[%d] is:%c\n", a, out[a]);
    }
}
void rev(char *in, char *out)
{
    if(a < 10)
    {
        a++;
        rev(in, out);
        out[9 - (--a)] = in[a];
    }
}
```

but it returns an @ at the end of array when I print the whole array while when I print array elements one by one, it doesn't exists.
please tell me what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rev` is reversing the entire `in` array, not just the part that contains the user's input. So it's copying the uninitialized values after the input.

The reason you're seeing different output when you print `out` than when you print the individual characters is because you're not adding a null byte to `out`. So printing the string goes past the end of the array when it looks for the null byte.

You should only reverse the part of the array up to `strlen(in)` rather than the entire array.

You also should pass `a` as a parameter, not use a global variable.

And finally, when you reach the end you need to add a null byte to the output string.

```
void rev(char *in, char *out, start, len)
{
    if(start < len)
    {
        rev(in, out, start + 1, len);
        out[len - start-1] = in[start];
    } else {
        out[start] = '\0';
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
rev(in, out, 0, strlen(in));
```

Comment: I can't understand why when I print it's elements, @ doesn't appear?and why we copy parts out of user input?

Comment: I think you're not copying the null byte when you do the reverse. So when you print the whole string it goes past the end.